# 'dpkg-deb' error while installing anything Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

```
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
dpkg: warning: 'dpkg-deb' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin

echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you can still run dpkg, at least part of the dpkg package is still present. To restore dpkg-deb, you should try re-installing dpkg:

download the appropriate package file (Mint 18.3 is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so look for Xenial on this page to get the appropriate links; the download link I’m giving here assumes you’re using amd64)

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
install it

sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
```

If that fails, you’ll need to resort to a more manual approach as suggested in arved’s answer:

```
ar x dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb data.tar.gz
tar xf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg-deb
sudo install usr/bin/dpkg-deb /usr/bin
```

Then install the package using dpkg to make sure everything’s set up properly.